# How to get CSS keyframe rules in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, keyframe

I have an external CSS file, lets say my.css with content:

```
@keyframes someName {  
  0% {   
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 100px; 
  }    
  100% {   
    opacity: 1;
    width: 200px;   
  }    
}  
@keyframes someName2 {  
  0% {   
    height: 100px; 
  }    
  100% {   
    height: 200px;   
  }    
}
```

I want to create an object from this, with structure as in:

```
{
  somename : {
     0: { opacity: 0, width: 100 }
   100: { opacity: 0, width: 200 }
  }
  somename2: {
     0: { height: 10 }
   100: { height:  80 }
  }
}
```

How do I do this in JQuery? I am not looking for complete code. How do I access CSS keyframes by name in JQuery? Something along the lines:

```
  $('someCSS Selector').css('keyframes'...)?
```

Comment: @VXp  I know how to use animation. My question is to covert the keyframes CSS to the object.

Comment: @VXp  That deals with creating animations not querying existing one.

Comment: @VXp Not a duplicate. OP wants to get, not set

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquerykeyframes

Comment: @VXp This should be relatively simple. I am missing something here... I do not want to use a plugin for this. Besides, from a quick perusal, jquerykeyframes does not have what I want.

Comment: [You can try this](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/#article-header-id-6).  It's native js but better than nothing

Comment: @VXp As far as I can see, jquerykeyframes doesn't let you retrieve CSS Keyframes for the stylesheet. Just the ability to set them

Comment: @VXp Yes your reference is a good starting point. Hopefully, I get a JQuery one which will handle browser issues for rule type (webkit-keyframes, keyframes, etc.)

Comment: @Pete I tried it. It does not work. document.styleSheets returns an object and there are no sub-properties like name and type to cssRules

Comment: @Pete it does not work if the CSS is in an external file using <link...>

Comment: In that case it's probably not possible so you should rethink your approach, as you have not said what you need the end object for it's impossible to say if there is a better approach